# Windows App Store Logo

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Having finally managed to get my windows store app published, it is appearing in the store without its logo.  The logo file specified is a PNG file and is 150 x 150.  Clearly I need to link this in somewhere else, although I am at a loss to see where.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package-appmanifest file, under the packaging tab there is a "Logo" field.  This is where the store logo should be defined.

Comment: And its in Assets\StoreLogo.png, which is a file that is part of your project and listed as content?

Comment: is the actual name relevant?  Does it need to be called "StoreLogo.png"?  Mine is just "Logo".

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes:  the logo file I'm talking about is on the "Packaging" tab of the app manifest and should be 50 by 50, not 150 by 150.  I think you're looking at the logo field on the "Application UI" tab of the manifest (which is 150 by 150).  What image are you using for the logo field on the "Packaging tab"?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure StoreLogo.png (50 X 50) exists is `Assets` directory & check by double clicking `Package.appxmanifest -> Packaging Tab -> You have linked the Store logo`

Logo : `Assets\StoreLogo.png`